# Texture gets cut off when mipmaps are disabled

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my project, I'm drawing pixels on a texture using texture.SetPixels and applying them using texture.Apply();

Everything works fine but If I disable the mipmap by adding 'false' to Apply, I get this weird behavior.

Here is a gif demonstrating that: https://gifyu.com/image/STP4f

Any ideas?